# How can i make following Javascript code work?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript.I stick to one problem. I want same function to generate same result for this code:

```
Multiply(5, 2); // return 10
Multiply(5)(2); // return 10
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what is the problem with the code you have tried?

Comment: I just dont get the approach how will i do that.Is the problem related to closure??

Comment: So you want a function which either returns a number when two arguments are present or returns a function when one argument is present.  Have you tried to write this?

Comment: Yes but didnt get success.

Comment: so show your attempt !

Comment: @Andrew1221: Pro tip: "I tried this code, and this is the specific way it's not working" is a valid question here.  "I give up, someone show me how to do it" is not.

Comment: The technique you look for is called _currying_.

Comment: Thanks @t.niese.This is exactly concept which I  am looking for.Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

It would be what you want.

```js
function Multiply(a, b){
  if(b != null){
    return a*b;
  }
  return function(c){
    return a*c;
  }
}

console.log(Multiply(5, 2));
console.log(Multiply(5)(2));
```

Comment: Thanks mate.Perfect solution